# What would people who have never seen a plane before call it?

Tags: society, language, dystopia, future

In my story, my characters live in the wilderness, and they have no modern technology. They do see ruins from the past (from now) but other than that they have no idea how advanced other parts of the world might be, or of technology of the past. However, they often see the plane of a more advanced civilization (they are monitoring them to stop them from getting better technology) flying over them. It is thin and grey, very efficient but not too hard to see. I don't want these people, after seeing the plane for hundreds of years, to look up at it and go, 'it looked like a metal bird' because that seems so cliche. **What word could I have them use for it instead?** Honestly I would take anything that sounds like a real word and isn't super cheesy.

They're British, if that helps.

Comment: I think it's called magic.

Comment: This seems somewhat off-topic and somewhat opinion-based. On one hand, coming up with an in-world attribute of an object is relevant to the site; on the other hand, this feels much more geared Writing SE in that it's more about how to write a character's experience in a non-cliche way than it is about constructing the world the character inhabits. Plus, how can a correct answer be chosen objectively when all names for planes are equally valid?

Comment: They're called birds.  See how Amazonian tribes, who had never lived anywhere you could see more than 500 feet ahead of you (for the canopy), related to ships near the horizon.

Answer (score 4):

You said you're against the idea of calling it a metal bird, but are there any other things the characters are aware of that fly around in the sky? If they are describing the plane to someone, they are trying to relate it to something the other person is familiar with Birds being the obvious "cliche" choice is a good answer. Obvious is good so the other person can relate to the object's properties in the most efficient manner.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Kindapink. Would the characters be aware it was made of metal?

Comment: Perhaps we can get some clarification from the OP - what stage of civilization have these people regressed to? If they haven't seen copper/iron/bronze they'd be less likely to say 'metal bird'. Maybe shiny bird? Or watery bird (metal has a shiny reflection sometimes)? Maybe an angel/messenger from their gods?

Comment: I was thinking that it has been so long that they recognize it when it goes overhead and have made up an entirely new work for it

Answer (score 1):

Cloud bird or the-cloud-that-moves. They would not know that it was made of metal if they only saw it in the sky and had no other knowledge of it, and it’s height would clearly be greater than that of any other bird they saw